# How to make post request data from android when after clicking button using Restsharp

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, restsharp

i tried below code in Xamarin studio, building a solution is ok no error, run and test it on android emulator but not getting data in database. And also enable internet permission too.

code for handling to call rest services

```
using RestSharp;
...
using System.Json;
namespace DemoAndroid
{

    public class RestClass
    {
        public void insert(string text1, string text2, string text3, string text4, int text5)
        {
            var client = new RestClient("http://192.168.1.34/test/v1/");                                                
            var request = new RestRequest("postdata", Method.POST);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddBody(new 
                {
                    name = text1,
                    address= text2,
                    city = text3,
                    country = text4,
                    uid = text5
                });
            client.Execute(request);
        }
    }
}
```

main activity class for posting data

```
namespace DemoAndroid
{
    [Activity (Label = "DemoAndroid", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        RestClass aa = new RestClass();
        EditText editText1, editText2, editText3, editText4, editText5;
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);
            Button button1 = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button1);
            editText1 = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.editText1);
            editText2 = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.editText2);
            editText3 = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.editText3);
            editText4 = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.editText4);
            editText5 = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.editText5);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            button1.Click += delegate {
                aa.insert(editText1.Text, editText2.Text, editText3.Text, editText4.Text, int.Parse(editText5.Text));
        }
    }
}
}
```

this are example of api link and parameters for posting data

```
http://192.168.1.34/test/v1/postdata
name, address, city, country, uid
```

my api work fine in any rest client app, give this response after successfully inserted

```
{
message: "successfully inserted"
}
```

Also i try to show message response in toast whether the data has inserted or not when after clicking button, please suggest me how to do this and why posting data can not inserted in db.
i check it in many sites of example android with Restsharp for post data but cant't found.
Thank you

Comment: When you debug, do you get all the way to `client.Execute(request);`?

Comment: Thank you @Halvard, i dont see any about client.Execute(request);  not very sure how to check it, can you please tell me how do i check it and to solved this.

Comment: `client.Execute(request)` is from your own code you are showing above.  I just wondered what happens when you debug this using Xamarin Studio.  I mean, is `client.Execute(request)` actually called at all?  Sorry that I can't help you more than this ...

Comment: i check it while debugging does not see any process of client.Execute and check it fiddler too, not getting way of process to other end in fiddler.